# Write the value in the 8087's top of stack to a variable in memory

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I just installed a math coprocessor in my old 286 computer, and i've been playing around with it's instruction set in assembly.

I own the Intel programmer's reference for the 8086 CPU, and it has a nice long section on programming the 8087. I've learned almost everything I need to know from that section, but it never mentions how to actually transfer a value from the 8087's register stack into a memory variable.

There doesn't appear to be any 8087 instructions for moving data around, except for popping the stack and exchanging data around within the register stack.

So, how do I transfer st(0) into a temporary real variable in memory.

Comment: Did you miss the `FST` instruction?

Comment: Upvoted for having a real 286. You can still use the [modern manual](http://www.intel.it/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) or and [HTML version of it](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_117.html) for the instructions of the 8087.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did miss the FST instruction. I'm getting the wrong results, though. Here's the instructions i'm using `FLD testVar` (testVar = 2) `FADD testVar2` (testVar2 = 3)  `FST DWORD PTR shortReal` The value in shortReal comes out as FF C0 00 00, which does not seem to be a valid normalized short real.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work with the following instructions. `FLD testVar` `FLD testVar2` `FADD st, st(1)` `FST shortReal`

Comment: That leaves values on the x87 stack.  Try `fld testVar` / `fadd testVar2` / `fstp shortReal`.  See also the x87 tutorial link in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  [FADD can use a m32fp or m64fp](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FADD:FADDP:FIADD.html) memory operand.  Oh, that FF C0 00 00 is a NaN, right?  You probably ran your test with the x87 register stack already full, so you got an error.

Comment: Have fun with your actual 286 hardware, but keep in mind that modern x86 does (almost) all FP math using SSE instructions in XMM registers.  (e.g. assuming your inputs are 64-bit doubles, `movsd xmm0, testVar` / `addsd xmm0, testVar2` / [`cvtsd2ss`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSD2SS.html) / `movss shortReal, xmm0`

Comment: @Peter Cordes - Thanks man, I figured out that I was causing a stack overflow an hour or so, after asking this question. I didn't realize that values remained resident in the 8087 stack even after the program ends.

Comment: Wow, I would have assumed like you did that DOS would FNINIT between programs.  Proper multi-tasking OSes like Linux and Windows do start each process with consistent state (including stuff like DF cleared), as required by the ABI.